# Open multiple files in vim some Read Only and some Read and Write

Tags: vim

I know I can open files in Read only mode `vim -R file` and I can open multiple files with `vim file1 file2`. Is there a way, when opening multiple files at once, to open selected files as read only while others are read and write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.  Your best bet is to `:set readonly` when editing the files you don't want to modify.